# Multithreading in Matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I have the following program flow, with a big Datablock `D`

```
S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> S4
```

Where `S1` and `S4` both read and write `D`. `S2` and `S3` both only read `D`.

Now I would like to create the following program flow in `matab`

```
  S1 ->  S2  -> Wait for S2 and S3 to finish -> S4
     |       |
     +-> S3 -+
```

where `S2` and `S3` are executed in parallel. My Question is how to achieve that without copying `D`, since this is shouldn't be necessary (no locking required) and it is big.

Answer (score 1):

Using Matlab-Code that is not possible. There is no multi-threading in matlab.

There exists the parallel computing toolbox, but this toolbox uses multiple processes, which requires copying at least the used parts of D to the workers.

The only possibility for multi threading i am aware of is implementing S2 and S3 as one mex-function (C or C++ code), using OpenMP or similar.

Comment: This is interesting. I may be wrong but as I understand it Matlab *does* some multithreading internally, for instance with figure callbacks and `uiwait`. I wonder if one could exploit this to "simulate" multithreading in Matlab ...

Comment: Using `uiwait` will probably have the same results as the solutions based on `timer` proposed [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1)